# How to bulk-update using sqlalchemy core? Different columns updated for each entry

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bulkupdate

While I can update multiple values if I know the columns before hand, I have trouble creating a bulk update if one doesn't wish to hard code the column values.

Consider the following:

```
stmt = task_table.update() \
    .where(task_table.c.id == bindparam('idx')) \
    .values(bindparam('values'))
vals = [{'idx': task.idx, 
         'values':{'queueStatus': task.queue_status, 'detail':str(task.idx)}}
        for task in actions]

connection.execute(stmt, vals)
connection.commit()
```

This gives the error `AttributeError: Neither 'BindParameter' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'items'`. In the `values()`

I could change it to something like:

```
stmt = task_table.update() \
    .where(task_table.c.id == bindparam('idx')) \
    .values({queueStatus=bindparam('values'), detail=bindparam('detail')})
vals = [{'idx': task.idx, 
         'values':task.queue_status, 'detail':str(task.idx)}
        for task in actions]

connection.execute(stmt, vals)
connection.commit()
```

However this would require me to always give all columns - even if I don't want to update these columns.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I can see from your example is that you are trying to unpack multiple values without indicating what is the specific column you want to update, also pay attention to the restricted names used for the bindparams, something like this should work:

```
stmt = (
    task_table.update()
        .where(task_table.c.id == bindparam('_idx'))
        .values(
        queueStatus=bindparam('_queue_status'),
        detail=bindparam('_detail')
    )
)
vals = [
    {
        '_idx': task.idx,
        '_queue_status': task.queue_status,
        '_detail': str(task.idx),
    }
    for task in actions
]

connection.execute(stmt, vals)
connection.commit()
```

This is documented in the [the sqlalchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#inserts-updates-and-deletes):

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to explain here, the only difference with what? And secondly, how would this help me when each update only has a subset of columns to update? Ie the first few tasks have `queue_status = None` which means it's to be ignored/not udpated, then I have a few tasks the `detail` set to `None` and finally there is a set of tasks that have both set to a real value. (And in the actual test there are 6 columns, and thus a huge amount of combinations of 'values that need to be updated').

Comment: Looks like the last line of my comment should be the first to make sense.

Also, I misread the question, in which SQL DB can you perform a bulk update where each row contains a different number/type of columns?
Not sure sqlalchemy core will be able to help if the DB does not have such feature.

Comment: Well the problem is, I notice that our application runs slow, and most of the time it is waiting to establish new connection to our database, and only sending a few updated (single) entries each time. So I wish to bulk-send the data to the database server and let the server itself "handle" the input.